# I don't understand the small signal model of this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, small-signal

I have a book that contains the solutions to certain problems that states that the small signal model for this circuit:

[image]

is this:

[image]

I don't understand it. Why is \$Z_L\$ in parallel with the VCVS \$g_mv_i\$? Shouldn't it be in series?

Comment: I'm sorry but I've rolled back your question to how it was when I answered it. Please do be careful when making question amendments that subsequently contradict answers given in good faith that point out errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation "\$V_S\$" near the top of the diagram indicates a constant voltage source connected from ground to the \$V_S\$ node.

In small signal analysis, constant voltage sources become short circuits. After making this transformation, the load components (R, L, and C) are connected from the \$v_o\$ node to ground, and thus in parallel with the current source in the Norton equivalent of the transistor's drain-source branch.

Answer (score 1):

Why is \$Z_L\$ in parallel with the VCVS \$g_mv_i\$? Shouldn't it be in series?

- It's not a VCVS
- It's a voltage controlled **current** source (VCCS).
- Secondly, with current sources, the impedance is put in parallel.

Various dependent sources: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/dependent-sources-in-electrical-networks--554787247849909234/)